# Open Cart SEO different aspect

Tags: php, url-rewriting, seo, opencart

I have a doubt regarding open cart SEO. First I would mentioned that, I already know about SEO and I can successfully made my SEO link works.

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?route=product_id=18
```

will trigger

```
www.mysite.com/old_woody_bag
```

after the click on the menu by the function of $this->url->link in the href.

But then is there anyway to change the link automatically when I PASTE straight away into the URL.

paste

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?route=product_id=18
```

in the url and hit ENTER.

it cannot automatically changed to

```
www.mysite.com/old_woody_bag
```

I found some site talking about changing index.php to check the link and redirect to SEO or by changing .htaccess to force the link into SEO. But I do not understand how it really works. By the way, my condition is to avoid touching .htaccess file. Is there anyone already did it out there? Kindly tell me if there is already some hidden post about this and I will remove this post. Thank you! Your help is also much appreciated!

Comment: If You knew about SEO then You wouldn't ask this question. `www.mysite.com/old_woody_bag` is not correct SEO link, but `www.mysite.com/old-woody-bag` is. Anyway, if You have SEO links turned on then normal visitor would have no clue nor reason to guess the *non-SEO* URLs and to hit them in the browser. And even if the visitor would do that this would have no effect on Your SEO. The only important think for Your SEO is that the links on Your site are generated in SEO way. So what is this question all about?

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, yes the customer would not know our non SEO link. but somehow to prevent in case if the customer knows it or not. Im just asked to see if there is any alternative to solve this. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do agree with you Polar, sometime it happen that the crawler stat indexing non SEO url and you are end up with having two different copy (URL) of same page in search engine index.

I studied your requirement and strongly recommend doing permanent redirection from non seo to seo url. I am not sure how to do it in open cart but i am sure you will find some plugin for that (if you don't want to touch .htaccess file).

Comment: ok. thank you for your opinion. I will need to do even deeper research from now on. =)